# Cygwin window- can't run ruby command "hello world"

Tags: ruby, image, bash, cygwin

I am using **Cygwin** and had installed two necessary packages which are **ImageMagick** and **ruby** to convert image in **.LJPEG** to **.png**.

My problem is when I verify that the ruby program was installed correctly by typing

> ruby -e "p 'Hello world'"

in the Cygwin window, I got this nothing printed but when I run using `` instead of '';

> ruby -e "p `Hello world`"

, I got -bash: hello: command not found.

Where is my mistake?

I need it to print `Hello world` to verify that Ruby program was installed correctly.

Comment: you can type `ruby -v` instead to see if Ruby is installed.

Comment: I'd typed it and nothing printed out. Does it mean ruby doesnt installed correctly? What do you suggest? Install ruby independently?

Comment: Maybe try the ruby shell. It's a program you download for windows

Comment: Is your installation of `cygwin` itself dodgy, rather than `ruby`? Does basic STDOUT work, e.g. running `echo "hello world"`?

Comment: @TomLord, what do you mean by `dodgy`? Yes, if I run `echo "hello world"` it get printed out. but not with ruby -e "p `hello world`".

Comment: @maxpleaner, actually I didnt know the exact function of ruby in the cygwin.  My goal for cygwin is to convert .LJPEG image into .png format so that the image that I need can be read by matlab. I dont know whether ruby is necessary or not to be installed independently as I just follow the tutorial given here `https://github.com/trane293/DDSMUtility` where it need me to install the package during cygwin setup. my problem now is that my matlab command wndow does not produce the image after conversion after I run the script. I think maybe one of the problem is because of the ruby.

Comment: By "dodgy", I mean: *"I have no idea why running `ruby -v` would produce **no output**"*. I would expect that command to *always* either display your ruby version, or a `ruby: command not found` error message. Does running `irb` work?

Comment: do I just need to type `irb` after `$`? if yes, it also doesnt work. nothing printed out.

Comment: `$ ruby -v` should produce and output like `ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-cygwin]` If you have no output follow https://www.cygwin.com/problems.html and ask support on the cygwin mail list.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.